# Using a custom js file as a module

Tags: javascript, module, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs to parse XML sitemap to get URLs and then check Google Analytics request on these URLS.

I wrote a parsexml.js file which works fine but I fail to use it as a module in my checkRequest.js file

Here is the parsexml.js code (works fine):

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    urls, 
    sites,
    output;

page.open(encodeURI('http://www.somesite.com/sitemap.xml'), function(status) {
if (status !== "success") {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    urls = page.content.match(/<loc>(.*)<\/loc>/ig);
    output = '';
    if (urls == null) {
        console.log('Pas d\'URL dans le fichier');
    } else {
        urls.forEach(function(url) {
            url = url.replace(/<.*?>/g, '');
            sites = 'sites.push(' + url + ');';
            output = output + sites;
        });
    }
    console.log(output);
    phantom.exit();
}
});
```

Here is how I tried to modify it to use it as a module:

```
exports.parsing = function () {
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    urls, 
    sites,
    output;

page.open(encodeURI('http://www.somesite.com/sitemap.xml'), function(status) {
if (status !== "success") {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
        //phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        urls = page.content.match(/<loc>(.*)<\/loc>/ig);
        output = '';
        if (urls == null) {
            console.log('Pas d\'URL dans le fichier');
        } else {
            urls.forEach(function(url) {
                url = url.replace(/<.*?>/g, '');
                sites = 'sites.push(' + url + ');';
                output = output + sites;
            });
        }
        console.log(output);
        //phantom.exit();
    }
});
}
```

And finally how I tried to call the module in my final js file:

```
var xml = require('./parseXML.js');
xml.parsing();
```

I must be missing something obvious but I'm searching for hours now and I feel really lost.

Comment: In what way is it failing?  What error are you getting?

Comment: The output is empty when using the module while the output is a list of sites.push(urls) as expecting using the first file. But I do not get error.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem with PhantomJS 1.9.7. It works fine with https://developer.mozilla.org/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

After a read through [this page](http://soledadpenades.com/2013/11/01/modules-in-phantomjs/) I came up with two solutions.
In the first you just drop the file extension in require():

```
var xml = require('./parsexml');
xml.parsing();
```

The second solution is useful if you want to call function by a different name in your external file. So parsexml.js now looks like:

```
function parsing() {
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    urls,
    sites,
    output;

page.open(encodeURI('http://www.somesite.com/sitemap.xml'), function(status) {
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
        //phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        urls = page.content.match(/<loc>(.*)<\/loc>/ig);
        output = '';
        if (urls == null) {
            console.log('Pas d\'URL dans le fichier');
        } else {
            urls.forEach(function(url) {
                url = url.replace(/<.*?>/g, '');
                sites = 'sites.push(' + url + ');';
                output = output + sites;
            });
        }
        console.log(output);
        //phantom.exit();
    }
});
}

function pinapples() {
    console.log("Pinapples.");
}

module.exports = {
    parsing: parsing,
    name_a_fruit: pinapples
};
```

And checkRequest.js looks like:

```
var xml = require('./parsexml');
xml.parsing();
xml.name_a_fruit();
```

This should then output:

"Pinapples.
Unable to access network"

Answer (score -1):

```
function parsing()
{ 
    // ... your function
}

module.exports = {

    parsing: parsing

}
```